# Estimated marginal mean outside the range of data

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

Trying to estimate location for a binomial model I get some mean values outside the range of data. What am I doing wrong or how does the following come about?

[image: resulting_plot]

Individual probabilities (circles) are shown along with mean (square) and 95% CI (errorbar). I am fine with all the mean estimates except for Study 1, where the estimated mean for drug is somehow lower than any of individual probabilities for drug and the mean for control is higher than any of the individual probabilities for control.

```
# load libs
library('data.table')
library('emmeans')
library('ggplot2')
library('sandwich')

# make some data
dat <- data.table(
  Study = gl(4, 8),
  Treatment = gl(2, 4, 32, labels=c('Ctrl', 'Drug')),
  Sick = c(
    182, 114, 166, 213, 99, 160, 114, 71,
    140, 106, 207, 142, 31, 81, 162, 11, 
    364, 313, 268, 307, 103, 227, 132, 300,
    489, 704, 628, 680, 357, 405, 608, 642),
  Fine = c(
    366, 385, 314, 387, 415, 441, 283, 277,
    506, 802, 546, 616, 630, 650, 557, 668, 
    256, 386, 330, 264, 685, 644, 721, 507,
    374, 184, 207, 102, 745, 705, 432, 494)
)
dat[, Rate := round(Sick/(Sick + Fine), 3), Study]

# model
mod1 <- glm(cbind(Sick, Fine) ~ Treatment + Study, binomial(), dat)
res <- emmeans(mod1, c('Treatment', 'Study'), type = 'response', 
  infer = T, vcov=vcovHC)
res <- as.data.table(res)

# plot
ggplot(res, aes(Study, prob, col=Treatment)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=0.25), pch=15) +
  geom_point(data=dat, aes(Study, Rate, col=Treatment), 
    position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), 
    position = position_dodge(width=0.25)) +
  annotate("segment", x = 0.95, xend = 1.05, y = 0.178, yend = 0.178,
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(.2,"cm"))) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.7, y = 0.178, label='Mean?!') +
  annotate("segment", x = 1.2, xend = 1.2, y = 0.19, yend = 0.29,
    arrow = arrow(ends = "both", angle = 90, length = unit(.1,"cm"))) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.45, y = 0.25, label='Range')
```

Comment: Your graph shows values ranging from almost 0 up to 0.87, then below it you produce four numbers between 0.185 and 0.364.  Please explain in what sense these are "outside the measured values."  And what do "rep1," "NEG," and "POS" refer to?

Comment: @whuber: Annotated range of measured values and corresponding mean at issue. Moved the graph upwards to support the question better. Replaced variables with more self-explanatory names. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean that you want counts on the y-axis instead of probabilities?

Comment: @Dave: No. I see I still haven't made it clear enough. I have on the graph individual probabilities (circles) alongside with mean and 95%CI (square and pointrange, estimated by `emmeans` package in `r`). I am fine with all the mean estimates except for Study 1, something goes wrong there. The question is what exactly.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong in study 1? What do you see that you don't like?

Comment: @Dave: In Study 1, the estimated mean for drug is somehow lower than any of individual probabilities for drug and the mean for control is higher than any of the individual probabilities for control.

Comment: EMMs are based on the *model*, not (directly) on the data. You have fitted a pretty simple additive model without interaction, which forces the same difference (on the logic scale) between the two treatments with each study. If you fit a model with an interaction between Study and Treatment, I'll bet that won't happen.

Comment: @RussLenth: I suspected that, but wanted to learn more and leave a record for anyone stumbling upon similar in the future. You have emphasized again and again that EMMs are based on the model, but the way it played out here still came as a surprise to me (ignorance on my part). From what I understand, it is also not common use of EMM (abuse, perhaps) for it is EMM here for balanced design and over all the predictors.

Comment: I really don't know why this question was closed. It seems clear to me. I'd answer it for real if I could.

Comment: @Russ the reasons for the initial closure are spelled out in the first comment in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is due to the additive model that is fitted to these data. Such a model forces the treatment difference to be the same for each study. This is clearest if I show it on the logit scale:

```
> (EMM.add <- emmeans(mod1, ~ Treatment * Study, infer = T, vcov = vcovHC))
 Treatment Study  emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl      1     -0.5273 0.175 Inf    -0.870    -0.185 -3.017  0.0026 
 Drug      1     -1.5355 0.221 Inf    -1.969    -1.102 -6.939  <.0001 
 Ctrl      2     -1.3391 0.245 Inf    -1.819    -0.860 -5.474  <.0001 
 Drug      2     -2.3472 0.312 Inf    -2.959    -1.735 -7.520  <.0001 
 Ctrl      3     -0.0933 0.180 Inf    -0.445     0.259 -0.520  0.6032 
 Drug      3     -1.1014 0.228 Inf    -1.548    -0.655 -4.831  <.0001 
 Ctrl      4      0.9241 0.251 Inf     0.431     1.417  3.675  0.0002 
 Drug      4     -0.0840 0.244 Inf    -0.562     0.394 -0.344  0.7305 

Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Here are the comparisons for each study:

```
> pairs(EMM.add, by = "Study")
Study = 1:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug     1.01 0.229 Inf 4.410   <.0001 

Study = 2:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug     1.01 0.229 Inf 4.410   <.0001 

Study = 3:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug     1.01 0.229 Inf 4.410   <.0001 

Study = 4:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug     1.01 0.229 Inf 4.410   <.0001 

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.
```

If on the other hand, we fit a model with interaction, those differences are allowed to depend on which study:

```
> mod2 <- glm(cbind(Sick, Fine) ~ Treatment * Study, binomial(), dat)
> EMM.int <- emmeans(mod2, ~ Treatment * Study, infer = T, vcov = vcovHC)
> pairs(EMM.int, by = "Study")
Study = 1:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug    0.394 0.210 Inf 1.871   0.0613 

Study = 2:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug    0.750 0.646 Inf 1.161   0.2457 

Study = 3:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug    1.224 0.386 Inf 3.173   0.0015 

Study = 4:
 contrast    estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Ctrl - Drug    1.226 0.497 Inf 2.467   0.0136 

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.
```

Note that, based on this model, the treatment difference is much smaller for Study 1 than the others. And the estimated means will be within the range of the data. All of this will hold up after converting to the response scale (probabilities).

This example also illustrates a common error -- thinking that we have "included everything" when in fact we only fitted an additive model. In practice, one should take some care to make sure that the model is adequate. Let's test the comparison of these two models:

```
> anova(mod1, mod2)
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: cbind(Sick, Fine) ~ Treatment + Study
Model 2: cbind(Sick, Fine) ~ Treatment * Study
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance
1        27    1085.36            
2        24     969.42  3   115.94

> ### P value:
> pchisq(115.9, 3, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 5.892728e-25
```

The deviance is a chi-square statistic, and its P value is miniscule, indicating that the interaction term is indeed needed.

Comment: In this particular case, the interaction is an inconvenient truth -- studies were carried out to be identical (that is not to say I am immune to the common error you point out). I'll have to give some thought to how to handle this now appropriately.